# Breaking out column by groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a DataFrame like this:

```
 type   value   group
    a      10     one
    b      45     one
    a     224     two
    b     119     two
    a      33   three
    b      44   three
```

how do I make it into this:

```
 type     one     two   three
    a      10     224      33
    b      45     119      44
```

I thought it'd be `pivot_table`, but that just gives me a re-grouped list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df.pivot(index='type', columns='group', values='value')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()

  type  one  three  two
0    a   10     33  224
1    b   45     44  119
```

If ordering of columns is important:

```
df = df.pivot(index='type', columns='group', values='value').rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print df[['one','two','three']].reset_index()
  type  one  two  three
0    a   10  224     33
1    b   45  119     44
```

EDIT:

In your real data you can get error:

```
print df.pivot(index='type', columns='group', values='value')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()
```

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

```
print df
  type  value  group
0    a     10    one
1    a     20    one
2    b     45    one
3    a    224    two
4    b    119    two
5    a     33  three
6    b     44  three
```

Problem is in second row - you get for index value `a` and column `one` two values - `10` and `20`. Function [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) aggregate data in this case. Dafault aggregating function is `np.mean`, but you can change it by parameter `aggfunc`:

```
print df.pivot_table(index='type', columns='group', values='value', aggfunc=np.mean)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()

  type  one  three  two
0    a   15     33  224
1    b   45     44  119

print df.pivot_table(index='type', columns='group', values='value', aggfunc='first')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()

  type  one  three  two
0    a   10     33  224
1    b   45     44  119

print df.pivot_table(index='type', columns='group', values='value', aggfunc=sum)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()

  type  one  three  two
0    a   30     33  224
1    b   45     44  119
```