# Converting from Deep to wide format in pandas without Memory errors

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks more like below which contains *person Id* , *characteristics* and the *count*. This is currently in deep/long format.

```
Person Id   Characteristics Count
123          Apple            2
123          Banana           4
124          Pineaple         1
125          Apple            2
```

I want to efficiently convert this into a wide format and create a matrix which needs to be fed into an algorithm for reducing components.

It should look something like below

```
Person Id   Apple   Banana  Pineapple
123           2       4        0
124           0       0        1
125           2       0        0
```

I am looking for an efficient way of doing this . Currently there is about 2000+ Characteristics and so there will be about 2000 or more columns and about 300K person Ids.

As you can see if there is no characteristic present, we need to fill it with zeroes. My approach seems to be clogging up a lot of memory and i was getting memory errors.

I am confused as to how to implement this in a efficient way.

Comment: What is your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`), but pivoting need much memory:

```
print df.pivot_table(index='Person Id', 
                     columns='Characteristics', 
                     values='Count', 
                     fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

   Person Id  Apple  Banana  Pineaple
0        123      2       4         0
1        124      0       0         1
2        125      2       0         0
```

Maybe faster is:

```
print df.pivot(index='Person Id', 
               columns='Characteristics', 
               values='Count').fillna(0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

   Person Id  Apple  Banana  Pineaple
0        123    2.0     4.0       0.0
1        124    0.0     0.0       1.0
2        125    2.0     0.0       0.0
```

**Timings**:

```
In [69]: %timeit df.pivot_table(index='Person Id',  columns='Characteristics',  values='Count',  fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.26 ms per loop

In [70]: %timeit df.pivot(index='Person Id',  columns='Characteristics',  values='Count').fillna(0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is possible for the Person Id to repeat, this is causing `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: Do you think error in `pivot` ? I think then `pivot_table` works.

Comment: Difference between this two functions are explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36998097/2901002).